# Bash Scripting in AIX

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to search a keyword like "errors" in a log output file and output the whole string. For example, the file has "the record was unable to process due to errors found in the previous statement", and I want to be able to find every instance of "errors" occurrence and output the whole associated sentence in a separate output file. 
Should I use a find or grep and how do I output the whole string?

Comment: `grep errors logfile.txt`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Note also that an ideal title *is specific to your individual question* (not just what tools you're trying to use, but exactly what you're trying to do with them); and an ideal question shows your attempts and where you got stuck ("X works on Linux, but when I try it on AIX, it gives me error Y").

Comment: And how do I keep a tally of all the "hits" and report the total in output file. So for example, if I found 5 "errors", I should report total of 5 found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep error file.log > errors.txt
```

Search by log with output to the result file

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, particularly the bullet point regarding questions that "are not about programming as defined in the help center".